# How to use sockets in Lean?

Tags: sockets, lean

How do I create a TCP socket in Lean 4 and accept an incoming connection or connect to a remote address? In other words, how do I implement a TCP server or client in Lean 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap the socket types and functions to use them in Lean 4.

Lean 4 is still in an early stage, even without a stable release. There is very few packages for Lean now, so you cannot expect production level packages like Python's `socket` or Rust's `std::net`/`mio`.

But if you just want to take a try, you can look at my [`lean4-socket`](https://github.com/xubaiw/lean4-socket) package, which is a toy implementation. There are also simple examples e.g. sending HTTP request (which is based on TCP) in the `examples` folder.

Comment: There are still many obstacles on Lean 4's road to a general purpose programming language. For example, the current FFI is still very complicated (can be solved by some metaprogramming but some pondering is required), and the libraries is very few (everything from scratch to make a https request)...

Answer (score 2):

There is a rudimentary but working implementation of a socket API [here](https://github.com/xubaiw/lean4-socket) which you can use with Lean 4 and Lake. It also has two examples that demonstrate its use.